# use uno (openoffice api) to open spreadsheet *without* recalculation

Tags: openoffice-calc, uno, pyuno

I'm using pyuno to read an excel spreadsheet (running on linux.) Many cells have formulas referring to addins that are, obviously, not available. However the cell values are what I want.

But when I load and read the sheet, it seems those formulas are being evaluated and thus the values are being overwritten with errors.

I've tried several things, none of which have worked:

- set flags AutomaticCalculation=False, MacroExecutionMode=NEVER_EXECUTE in the call to desktop.loadComponentFromURL
- call document.enableAutomaticCalculation(False) on the loaded document

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that those values are actually stored? If they are not, there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If formluas aren't a matter, you might circumvent the problem by processing a copy of your spreadsheet in which only the values (not the formulas) are present.

To achieve this quickly, select the whole sheet content, copy, special paste; then remove everything except "value". Save to a new file (make sure you don't overwrite the original file or every formula will be lost!). Your script should then be able to process this file.

This is an ugly solution, as there must be a way to do it programmaticaly.

Comment: Simpler is just open excel, set Calc Mode to manual, load spreadsheet, then resave. Now it will have its calc mode set to manual and OO will respect that when loading it. But this defeats the purpose of using OO which was to be independent of excel. If I'm using excel to this extent I might as well go all the way and not use OO at all.

Answer (score 0):

Calc does not yet support using the cached results after loading the document. Libreoffice Calc does now use cached results for xls documents. The results are also stored in ods but are ignored while loading the document and the formula result is evaluated by compiling and interpreting the saved formula.

There are some plans to add this for ods and xlsx too but there are many ods producers out there writting incorrect results in the file. So till now the only solution is to have a second version of the document only saving the results (or implementing it inside calc).

Comment: Thanks for this info. Just to be clear: Libreoffice Calc uses the stored values for xls, but not for xlsx? Then that too isn't a viable solution. Re incorrect results in the file: why not leave the choice up to the user whether to recalculate or use the existing results? Ironic that MS is usually the one that decides it knows better than the user, but in this case it's the one that gives the user the option.

Comment: Just because nobody implemented this until know. For XLSX it might get tricky but for ODS it is planned and hopefully will be implemented soon.

Comment: Still don't understand -- why not give the user the choice? Apparently the developers think they know better than the users whether an xlsx is "good" -- and to enforce their judgement will forbid the users to make the choice. The implementation has to be trivial -- just do *not* do the recalculation.